# What does M^(0,1) mean in this equation?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I typed 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\int f(x)M(x,y)dx)$$
into WolframAlpha and it said 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}( \int f(x) M(x, y) dx) = \int f(x) M^{0, 1}(x, y) dx$$

What does $M^{0,1}$ mean here? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Maybe $M^{a,b}$ means $\frac{\partial^{a}}{\partial x^a}\frac{\partial^b}{\partial y^b}M(x,y)$?